# SVG Как получить значение из SVG спрайта под нужный размер?

Tags: css, svg, svg-спрайт

Подскажите как из svg спрайта брать картинки через CSS с последующим масштабированием до нужных размеров/ Приведу пример

```css
.flags {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flag {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: ("https://svgshare.com/i/VxX.svg");
  background-size: 30px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 0;
}

.flag-usa {
  background-position-x: 0;
}

.flag-de {
  background-position-x: 640px;
}
```

```html
<img class="flags" src="https://svgshare.com/i/VxX.svg" alt='flags'>

<div class="flag flag-usa"></div>
<div class="flag flag-de"></div>
<div class="flag flag-fr"></div>
<div class="flag flag-it"></div>
<div class="flag flag-tr"></div>
<div class="flag flag-es"></div>
<div class="flag flag-po"></div>
```

Возможно ли из спрайта (viewBox="0 0 4480 480") забрать флаги 640х480 а потом в css подогнать под 30х20px ?  Не могу понять как тут область видимости работает

Comment: Через `<svg><use ...></svg>` проще делать, и не нужно просчитывать положение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`640х480` и `30х20` - получается непропорциональное уменьшение.

Если ширину `640px` уменьшить до `30px`, то высота соответственно, чтобы получилось пропорционально, должна быть `23px`.

Чтобы добиться вывода иконок нужного нам размера, пишем для этого следующие условия:

`background-size: 210px 23px;` - где значения:

`23px` - это высота, а `210px`- это ширина всех иконок (`7штук` * `30px`), `30px` - ширина одной иконки.

`background-position: 0 0;` - позиционирование. С каждой последующей иконкой сдвигаем на `30px` - на ширину одной иконки.

Вот пример:

<sub>* *Флаг usa кажется обрезанным, потому что он нарисован с браком.*</sub>

```css
.flags {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flag {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  background-color: #111;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/VxX.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 210px 23px;
}

.flag-usa {background-position: 0 0;}
.flag-de {background-position: -30px 0;}
.flag-fr {background-position: -60px 0;}
.flag-it {background-position: -90px 0;}
.flag-tr {background-position: -120px 0;}
.flag-es {background-position: -150px 0;}
.flag-po {background-position: -180px 0;}
```

```html
<img class="flags" src="https://svgshare.com/i/VxX.svg" alt='flags'>

<div class="flag flag-usa"></div>
<div class="flag flag-de"></div>
<div class="flag flag-fr"></div>
<div class="flag flag-it"></div>
<div class="flag flag-tr"></div>
<div class="flag flag-es"></div>
<div class="flag flag-po"></div>
```